# How to find if there is a Date Value in your column

Tags: regex, teradata

I Have a requirement in which I need to find Date in one my Column Value.

The Column has around 3 Million records and consists of Special characters, numbers, Text and date. Is there something I can do to find Date function and remove it from by Teradata Column.
Regex function can also help.

I don't know in which format the date function is.

Comment: If you don’t know what format your data is in, step one is not picking a tool for finding it. Step one is looking at your data so you do know.

Comment: As Jai wrote, how do you recognizea date? There must be a special format. Do you want to remove the date part from your output or mask it?

Comment: @Jai Jeffryes agree with you but I have around 33 million records and the date value may be around 50 records that's the challenge and that's why I don't know the date format

Comment: But how do you know there's a date? When you look at your data how would you spot that date? Something like groups of 2/2/4 digits seperated by a character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you don't know the contents of your data, your work is exploratory, meaning that your first step is to interrogate the data. Look for dates in as many formats as you can think of. You'll shake out the most common ones. I started you out with an approach I wrote in R. You can do something similar in the language of your choice.

You'll never know how many dates there are in formats you didn't think of. However, you can try some open-ended searches that might shake some of these out or even match defective data that you would like to see, but doesn't conform to any format. I included one search that just looks for a month abbreviation anywhere in the search string.

To make this demo, I had to cut and paste into the test cases every time I added a new RegEx to test. It would be a satisfying strategy to write a test bed. This could be a table or vector to hold each of the RegEx patterns you want to execute and then a simple loop that iterates through running them.

Here's my R code.

```
library(stringr)

# Exploratory date patterns.
# 04/04/2020
fmt1 <- "\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}"
# 4/4/2020
fmt2 <- "\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4}"
# Apr. 1, 2020
# If I have a large list, I like building it like this so the part I maintain
# is human readable. You can implement this kind of approach in whatever
# language you use.
month_3ltr <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May")
month_pat <- paste(month_3ltr, "\\.", sep = "")
month_pat <- paste(month_pat, collapse = "|")
fmt3 <- str_c("^(", month_pat, ")\\s\\d{1,2},\\s\\d{4}")
# Review pattern
fmt3
fmt4 <- str_c(month_pat) # Find anything that just mentions a month.
# Keep going, as many formats as you can think of.

# Test data
str1 <- "04/01/2020"
str2 <- "4/1/2020"
str3 <- "Apr. 1, 2020"
str4 <- "Defective data: Apr. First, 2020"
str5 <- "Fake news"

# Test cases
# Format 1
str_extract(str1, fmt1)
str_extract(str2, fmt1)
str_extract(str3, fmt1)
str_extract(str4, fmt1)
str_extract(str5, fmt1)

# Format 2
str_extract(str1, fmt2)
str_extract(str2, fmt2)
str_extract(str3, fmt2)
str_extract(str4, fmt2)
str_extract(str5, fmt2)

# Format 3
str_extract(str1, fmt3)
str_extract(str2, fmt3)
str_extract(str3, fmt3)
str_extract(str4, fmt3)
str_extract(str5, fmt3)

# Format 4
str_extract(str1, fmt4)
str_extract(str2, fmt4)
str_extract(str3, fmt4)
str_extract(str4, fmt4)
str_extract(str5, fmt4)
```

And my results:

```
> # Test cases
> # Format 1
> str_extract(str1, fmt1)
[1] "04/01/2020"
> str_extract(str2, fmt1)
[1] NA
> str_extract(str3, fmt1)
[1] NA
> str_extract(str4, fmt1)
[1] NA
> str_extract(str5, fmt1)
[1] NA
> 
> # Format 2
> str_extract(str1, fmt2)
[1] "04/01/2020"
> str_extract(str2, fmt2)
[1] "4/1/2020"
> str_extract(str3, fmt2)
[1] NA
> str_extract(str4, fmt2)
[1] NA
> str_extract(str5, fmt2)
[1] NA
> 
> # Format 3
> str_extract(str1, fmt3)
[1] NA
> str_extract(str2, fmt3)
[1] NA
> str_extract(str3, fmt3)
[1] "Apr. 1, 2020"
> str_extract(str4, fmt3)
[1] NA
> str_extract(str5, fmt3)
[1] NA
> 
> # Format 4
> str_extract(str1, fmt4)
[1] NA
> str_extract(str2, fmt4)
[1] NA
> str_extract(str3, fmt4)
[1] "Apr."
> str_extract(str4, fmt4)
[1] "Apr."
> str_extract(str5, fmt4)
[1] NA
```